# UserDefaults won't retrieve my string array correctly

Tags: arrays, swift, nsuserdefaults

I am trying to make a mechanism that lets users save items to favourites (which is an array) and then save that to UserDefaults, however I can't seem to get it to write to UD correctly. Printing UDSaved in the example below returns [], even though I just appended an element to the array.

**Does anyone have an idea what I'm doing wrong?**

Is it a syntax error and I am not retrieving this correctly or is there a problem with my logic?

```
var favouritesArray: [String] = []

func UDWrite() {UserDefaults.standard.set(favouritesArray, forKey: "UDfavouritesArray")}
let UDSaved = UserDefaults.standard.stringArray(forKey: "UDfavouritesArray") ?? [String]()


favouritesArray.append("element")
UDWrite()

print(UDSaved)
```

Comment: You don’t appear to be re-reading UDSaved after you have updated the defaults.

Comment: you are saving empty array and then getting it, after that adding string, try to add favouritesArray.append("element"), right after var favouritesArray: [String] = []

Comment: You do the following: Create an empty array `a`. Write `a` to a dictionary. Create an array `b` by reading `a` from a dictionary. Append something to `a`. Print `b`.

Comment: @DavidStockinger the function to write a to the dictionary is not called after a is created, it's called after I append something to a. So the order would be: - create an empty array A
- create an array B by reading A from the dictionary
- append something to A
- write A to the dictionary B I realise though I need to assign B the value of A as part of my function, and this seems to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As some stated in the comments: `UDSaved` never get's updated. My solution would be to make `UDSaved` a function like so:

```
var favouritesArray: [String] = []

func UDWrite() {UserDefaults.standard.set(favouritesArray, forKey: "UDfavouritesArray")}
func UDSaved() -> [String] {return UserDefaults.standard.stringArray(forKey: "UDfavouritesArray") ?? [String]}()

favouritesArray.append("element")
UDWrite()

print(UDSaved())
```

Or you could make it a computed property

```
var UDSaved: [String] {
   return UserDefaults.standard.stringArray(forKey: "UDfavouritesArray") ?? [String]
}
```

Comment: Thank you, and everyone who commented. I understand my mistake now and I fixed it by adding UDSaved = favouritesArray to my UDWrite() function and this fixed the problem.

Comment: Well `UDSaved = favouritesArray` helps as long as your app is running but this won't help to restore state after relaunching your app!

Comment: @CristianMoisei I'd highly recommend not doing that. When you can avoid modifying external variables inside functions, you should do so to keep your functions pure. Making `UDSaved` a computed property is a much better solution.

Comment: You're right @HerrderTöne I'll take some time to wrap my head around your solution (I'm relatively new to this) and do it that way. Thanks again.